How to cut/crop an image by custom vector
Is there a way to cut/crop some image (BMP/JPG etc) by defined vector (set of points that were got from DXF/DWG or SVG file)?
Currently, I'm getting vector points from SVG file and paint them like this:
var svgDoc = SvgDocument.Open(@"C:\Users\Desktop\Style 4.svg");
PointF[] pointsVector = svgDoc.Path.PathPoints;
// Draw closed curve to screen.
e.Graphics.DrawClosedCurve(greenPen, pointsVector);

I need to fill this vector with some image. Actually, I need to put center of my image to the center of the area of that vector.


Which programming language is this?

What do the red lines in the image mean?

I usually code on C#.
Red lines outside of black vector mean that I do not need that area. And need only the area inside black vector path.

And what do red lines inside the black area mean?

a red tick means that exactly the part inside the vector should remain

I don't think there is any built in method, but you can use FillPolygon to draw the polygon to an empty image, and use GetPixel / SetPixel to mask the pixels in the image.

Simplest method is flood fill the region outside the wanted line with a transparent colour and then select the smallest rectangular bounding box that is needed to contain the wanted part. No idea if this particular language supports those actions. Plenty of image processing packages do.

If you want to crop the shape as the title and the screenshot suggest, then yes you can do it as follows.
First, create a GraphicsPath for the curve and set it as the clipping region of the graphics used to draw the original image onto a new image of the same size.
Second, the GraphicsPath.GetBounds method returns the bounding rectangle of the shape (source rectangle) on the original image. Use its size to create the result image and create a Graphics object from it to draw the curve image.
internal static Bitmap CropCurve(Image srcImage, PointF[] points)
{
    using (var curveImage = new Bitmap(srcImage.Width, srcImage.Height))
    using (var gp = new GraphicsPath())
    {
        using (var g = Graphics.FromImage(curveImage))
        {
            gp.AddClosedCurve(points);
            gp.Flatten();

            g.SetClip(gp);
            g.DrawImage(srcImage, Point.Empty);
        }

        Rectangle srcRect = Rectangle.Round(gp.GetBounds());
        var resultImage = new Bitmap(srcRect.Width, srcRect.Height);

        using (var g = Graphics.FromImage(resultImage))
            g.DrawImage(curveImage, 0, 0, srcRect, GraphicsUnit.Pixel);

        return resultImage;
    }            
}



Use this instead if you need to translate the position of the shape to the center of the image.
private void SomeCaller()
{
    string imgFile = ...;
    PointF[] pointsVector = ...;

    using (var img = Image.FromStream(new MemoryStream(File.ReadAllBytes(imgFile)), true, false))
    using (var outImage = DrawShapeImage(img, pointsVector))
        outImage.Save("somePath", ImageFormat.Jpeg);
}

internal Bitmap DrawShapeImage(Image src, PointF[] shapePoints)
{
    Bitmap resImage = new Bitmap(src.Width, src.Height, src.PixelFormat);
    resImage.SetResolution(src.HorizontalResolution, src.VerticalResolution);

    using (var g = Graphics.FromImage(resImage))
    using (var clipPath = new GraphicsPath())
    using (var mx = new Matrix())
    {
        clipPath.AddClosedCurve(shapePoints);
        clipPath.Flatten();

        Rectangle srcRect = new Rectangle(Point.Empty, src.Size);
        RectangleF shapeRect = clipPath.GetBounds();

        mx.Translate(
            (src.Width - shapeRect.Width) / 2f - shapeRect.X,
            (src.Height - shapeRect.Height) / 2f - shapeRect.Y);
        clipPath.Transform(mx);

        g.SetClip(clipPath);
        g.DrawImage(src, Point.Empty);
    }

    return resImage;
}

The method does not crop or resize, it draws the clipping region from the given image and returns a new image of the same size as the source. The first example however shows you how to cut the shape and return it.

Here's an extended version which also allows you to scale the shape if needed. i.e. if the size of the canvas used to take the points and the size of the image are not equal.
internal Bitmap DrawShapeImage(Image src, PointF[] shapePoints, PointF scale)
{
    Bitmap resImage = new Bitmap(src.Width, src.Height, src.PixelFormat);
    resImage.SetResolution(src.HorizontalResolution, src.VerticalResolution);

    using (var g = Graphics.FromImage(resImage))
    using (var gp = new GraphicsPath())
    using (var mx = new Matrix())
    {
        gp.AddClosedCurve(shapePoints);
        gp.Flatten();

        Rectangle srcRect = new Rectangle(Point.Empty, src.Size);
        RectangleF shapeRect = gp.GetBounds();

        mx.Translate(
            (src.Width - shapeRect.Width) / 2f - shapeRect.X,
            (src.Height - shapeRect.Height) / 2f - shapeRect.Y);

        gp.Transform(mx);

        if (!scale.IsEmpty)
        {
            g.TranslateTransform(src.Width / 2, src.Height / 2);
            g.ScaleTransform(scale.X, scale.Y);
            g.TranslateTransform(-(src.Width / 2), -(src.Height / 2));
        }

        g.SetClip(gp);
        g.DrawImage(src, Point.Empty);
    }

    return resImage;
}


Hello @dr.null!
I'm getting black image without anything in it.
My code looks like that:
`FileStream imageTest = new FileStream("Mark.jpg",
FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read, FileShare.Read);
Image src = Bitmap.FromStream(imageTest);
var svgDoc = SvgDocument.Open(@"Style 4 15 ProMax.svg");
// vector from svg file as points array
PointF[] pointsVector = svgDoc.Path.PathPoints;
var resImage = CropCurve(src, pointsVector); // your code stays unchanged
resImage.Save("Mark_vect.jpg");`

@Ignat In your screenshot, if you're using a PictureBox to display the image and draw the path, what's the PictureBox.SizeMode value?

In my test app PictureBox.SizeMode is set to CenterImage. But I plan to use CropCurve on a set of files in particular directories and then display these updated images in telegram bot channel.

I'm woodworker :) and I have some knowledge in software engineering :) Source images are stays for wood and epoxy blanks that are going to be cnc machined accordingly to client's phone model. Then phone case will be created from this.

@Ignat Woodwork is an art. You have two problems here I need to understand. Is the position and size of the shape the same on all images? In other words, Are all images of the same size? Does the shape have be centered in any image?

The size of each source image (photo of the blank) should be standardized on my side. Yes, all images will be of the same size. The vector points differs from phone model to phone model. The shape have to be centered in any image, that is true.
Having chosen the blank, client going to see the preview and after cnc machining client will get exactly what was shown on preview. That's the idea of that :)

hello @dr.null. It seems that my way to get vector points works incorrectly (or I just do not have enough knowledge). Source file has these like points:
-262.5 -4.23 -127.01 -12.71 -127.01 -21.16 -118.55 -33.87 -114.31
-50.81 -105.85 -67.74 -93.14 -84.68 -71.98 -97.37 -63.5 -105.85
But reading this file by SvgDocument.Open I'm getting 7333.26,16678.07
5000.4395,16678.07
2663.3794,16678.07
2400.8794,16673.84
2273.8694,16661.129
2146.8594,16639.969
2028.3093,16606.1
1913.9993,16555.29
1808.1493,16487.549
1715.0093,16402.87
1643.0293,16305.499
It is too strange :(

Well, I did some experiments with my source files and got some pretty good result :) Polylines that I created in AutoCad I joined to make them as a single connected polyline. Then exported via CorelDraw as SVG file making 1:1 drawing precision and finally got some result. It is still not the result I need, but I see my image was "cut" by the shape from SVG file and it is too small. It is positioned in the center of the image, but too small :)

What I have now:



@Ignat Yes, you need to do the math and scale the shape. You're dealing with canvases of different sizes. Added new method for that.
